# Trouble connecting with facebook

Tags: facebook

Right now I am having trouble with my facebook login in js for my website.

This is all of the code:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '3',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            alert('whoo hoo!!! getLoginStatus called the callback');
        });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And I am getting this error:

> cxx.faceboo…:1 Application Error: There was a problem getting data for
>   the application you requested. The application may not be valid, or
>   there may be a temporary glitch. Please try again later.

I even edited my hosts file so that the domain points to my local machine.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Thank you!

Comment: You put an actual app id there, and not just `'3'`, right?

Comment: yes, I removed the original app id